# Java vs Ruby HMAC SHA256 don't agree

Tags: java, ruby, encryption, hmac

I can't get Ruby and Java to agree on a HMAC:

Ruby:

```
hmac_key = "my hmac key" #this is THE REAL KEY
msg = "fCyVmpFAZxv9Utui2QWGUtoGJ//Zr5aH+1PV31ry/dwX3yVdeEMIMW/dfoA9\nihbnYrnoSnb2yyfOrBYoy0JlDvWz8GJ6dY643lDTj7xcw8Q="
hashb16  = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('sha256', hmac_key, msg)
puts hashb16

052310d1fc91df4e5bbb47194cc401feed51eca98668b501555c78774dad6bed
```

Java:

```
String hmac_key = "my hmac key";
String encrypted_message_b64 = "fCyVmpFAZxv9Utui2QWGUtoGJ//Zr5aH+1PV31ry/dwX3yVdeEMIMW/dfoA9ihbnYrnoSnb2yyfO\nrBYoy0JlDvWz8GJ6dY643lDTj7xcw8Q=";
final Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(hmac_key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA256"));
byte[] signature = hmac.doFinal(encrypted_message_b64.getBytes("UTF-8"));
System.out.println(Hex.encodeHexString(signature));

d5bc0b58f43c6f6611f63822d22f99e18c51a33251a5a1c0c7712b4c7fb1ad24
```

Can you spot what's wrong?

---

Edit: I fixed the string that was badly copy/pasted.

Edit2: I reverted the fix, and use the proper content on ruby string so the answers and the accepted answer still make sense. Sorry for the mess

Comment: The Java contains an escaped newline (\n)

Comment: The Ruby too, and at a different place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The messages are different - see the `dfoA9\n` in the Ruby block.

Comment: Did you try using the same string? it still doesn't work

Comment: I originally did not run the code; I have now run the ruby version after changing b64_encoded => message. I installed the JDK and downloaded the commons-codec jar (it would have been helpful if you'd included the code block in a ready-to-run source file); but my Java is very rusty and I couldn't get it to run with the jar included.

Comment: Nevermind, it was a stupid copy/paste error because of newlines. Ruby has strict_encode64 which should prevent this; java should have this too.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you "fixed" by copy&pasting, the two source strings are still different (having `\n` at different places), and the hashes you posted are now equal. I suppose you don't have them equal, otherwise you won't be posting the question.

But what i see is that you are using `b64_encoded` as the Ruby input, which is not the `msg` you are showing us. Is there a chance it has a different content?